# R ggplot2 animation

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2

I cant create gif animation.
Using just example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(gapminder)
g <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, frame = year)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(aes(group = year), 
                  method = "lm", 
                  show.legend = FALSE) +
      facet_wrap(~continent, scales = "free") +
      scale_x_log10()  # convert to log scale

    gganimate(g, interval=0.2)
```

ImageMagick is installed. But I cant get animated gif, just following error:

```
I cannot find ImageMagick with convert = "convert"
but I can find it from the Registry Hive: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16
Executing: 
"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0 -delay 6 Rplot1.png
    Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png
    Rplot9.png Rplot10.png Rplot11.png Rplot12.png Rplot13.png Rplot14.png
    Rplot15.png Rplot16.png Rplot17.png Rplot18.png Rplot19.png Rplot20.png
    Rplot21.png Rplot22.png Rplot23.png Rplot24.png Rplot25.png Rplot26.png
    Rplot27.png Rplot28.png Rplot29.png Rplot30.png Rplot31.png Rplot32.png
    Rplot33.png Rplot34.png Rplot35.png Rplot36.png Rplot37.png Rplot38.png
    Rplot39.png Rplot40.png Rplot41.png Rplot42.png Rplot43.png Rplot44.png
    Rplot45.png Rplot46.png Rplot47.png Rplot48.png Rplot49.png Rplot50.png
    Rplot51.png Rplot52.png Rplot53.png Rplot54.png Rplot55.png Rplot56.png
    Rplot57.png Rplot58.png Rplot59.png Rplot60.png Rplot61.png Rplot62.png
    Rplot63.png Rplot64.png Rplot65.png Rplot66.png Rplot67.png Rplot68.png
    Rplot69.png Rplot70.png Rplot71.png Rplot72.png Rplot73.png Rplot74.png
    Rplot75.png Rplot76.png Rplot77.png Rplot78.png Rplot79.png Rplot80.png
    Rplot81.png Rplot82.png Rplot83.png Rplot84.png Rplot85.png Rplot86.png
    Rplot87.png Rplot88.png Rplot89.png "file2db411dd1405.gif""
"C:\Program" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
an error occurred in the conversion... see Notes in ?im.convert
Error in file(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c convert --version' had status 4 
2: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16/convert.exe": Не удается найти указанный файл
3: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0  -delay 6 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png Rplot11.png Rplot12.png Rplot13.png Rplot14.png Rplot15.png Rplot16.png Rplot17.png Rplot18.png Rplot19.png Rplot20.png Rplot21.png Rplot22.png Rplot23.png Rplot24.png Rplot25.png Rplot26.png Rplot27.png Rplot28.png Rplot29.png Rplot30.png Rplot31.png Rplot32.png Rplot33.png Rplot34.png Rplot35.png Rplot36.png Rplot37.png Rplot38.png Rplot39.png Rplot40.png Rplot41.png Rplot42.png Rplot43.png Rplot44.png Rplot45.png Rplot46.png Rplot47.png Rplot48.png Rplot49.png Rplot50.png Rplot51.png Rplot52.png Rplot53.png Rplot54.png Rplot55.png Rplot56.png Rplot57.png Rplot58.png Rplot59.png Rplot60.png Rplot61.png Rplot62.png Rplot63.png Rplot64.png Rplot65.png Rplot66.png Rplot67.png Rplot68.png Rplot69.png Rplot70.png Rplot71.png Rplot72.png Rplot73.png Rplot74.png Rpl [... truncated] 
4: In cmd.fun(convert) :
  выполнение '"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0  -delay 6 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png Rplot11.png Rplot12.png Rplot13.png Rplot14.png Rplot15.png Rplot16.png Rplot17.png Rplot18.png Rplot19.png Rplot20.png Rplot21.png Rplot22.png Rplot23.png Rplot24.png Rplot25.png Rplot26.png Rplot27.png Rplot28.png Rplot29.png Rplot30.png Rplot31.png Rplot32.png Rplot33.png Rplot34.png Rplot35.png Rplot36.png Rplot37.png Rplot38.png Rplot39.png Rplot40.png Rplot41.png Rplot42.png Rplot43.png Rplot44.png Rplot45.png Rplot46.png Rplot47.png Rplot48.png Rplot49.png Rplot50.png Rplot51.png Rplot52.png Rplot53.png Rplot54.png Rplot55.png Rplot56.png Rplot57.png Rplot58.png Rplot59.png Rplot60.png Rplot61.png Rplot62.png Rplot63.png Rplot64.png Rplot65.png Rplot66.png Rplot67.png Rplot68.png Rplot69.png Rplot70.png Rplot71.png Rplot72.png Rplot73.png Rplot74.png Rplot75.png Rplot76.png Rplot77.png Rpl [... truncated]
5: running command '"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe -loop 0  -delay 6 Rplot1.png Rplot2.png Rplot3.png Rplot4.png Rplot5.png Rplot6.png Rplot7.png Rplot8.png Rplot9.png Rplot10.png Rplot11.png Rplot12.png Rplot13.png Rplot14.png Rplot15.png Rplot16.png Rplot17.png Rplot18.png Rplot19.png Rplot20.png Rplot21.png Rplot22.png Rplot23.png Rplot24.png Rplot25.png Rplot26.png Rplot27.png Rplot28.png Rplot29.png Rplot30.png Rplot31.png Rplot32.png Rplot33.png Rplot34.png Rplot35.png Rplot36.png Rplot37.png Rplot38.png Rplot39.png Rplot40.png Rplot41.png Rplot42.png Rplot43.png Rplot44.png Rplot45.png Rplot46.png Rplot47.png Rplot48.png Rplot49.png Rplot50.png Rplot51.png Rplot52.png Rplot53.png Rplot54.png Rplot55.png Rplot56.png Rplot57.png Rplot58.png Rplot59.png Rplot60.png Rplot61.png Rplot62.png Rplot63.png Rplot64.png Rplot65.png Rplot66.png Rplot67.png Rplot68.png Rplot69.png Rplot70.png Rplot71.png Rplot72.png Rplot73.png Rplot74.png Rplot75.png Rplot76.png Rplot77.pn [... truncated] 
6: In file(file, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkzDzx4/gganimate\file2db411dd1405.gif': No such file or directory
```

What does it mean? That I didnt allow R to create gif-formated pictures? Something is missed? R version isnt appropriate?
Thank you.

Comment: ImageMagick 7 uses magick rather than convert. Be sure that your animation program is consistent with ImageMagick 7; otherwise uninstall it and reinstall ImageMagick 6.

Comment: Is ImageMagick installed at "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16/convert.exe"?

Comment: Thanks, going to check it soon!